# Processing excel file for previous entries

Tags: c#, sql, excel, scripting

I have an excel file that is updated every X minutes and I need to download it and remove any past entries from it before I send to my database. Downloading easy. Importing Easy. Processing that excel file for the previous entries is where I am kind of scratching my head.

I am wondering about fast and efficient ways to do this without a lot of code. I feel kind of dense asking this question as it seems simple, but not sure of the best route.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your 'Easy' Importing method?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be with ADO, but that would mean some code eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166. Is this an option for you?

Comment: sql*loader..should have noted DB is oracle

Comment: In that case, it should be possible to select only new entries, it certain is possible with SQL Server : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564532/mvc-load-data-from-excel-to-sqlserver/4564779#4564779

Comment: That changes things.  I'm purely a sql guy, but this tool looks like its worth a look http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickload/

Answer (score 0):

Man, that sure sounds like a scary app to build.  If I absolutely had to do it I would use VSTO to [suck the data out](http://dotnetperls.com/excel) as text and perform diff's with the last version.  Hopefully you won't have much concurrency to deal with, but even issues like whitespace can give you a mass headache.  I can only imagine how many problems can come out of this kind of an application.

Excel a db it is not.  Hopefully those X minute updates are as predictable as a machine.

I would highly recommend you start collecting as many of these excel sample files as you can and pump all of them into some unit tests.

Comment: It is pretty easy to open a spreadsheet as a recordset with a jet connection in VBA, why is it better to run it through VSTO as text?

Comment: @Remou pick your poisen, makes little difference which hammer he picks.  The potential for problems comes from the lack of DB like constraints in Excel.