# How do I compare two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, diff

Our organization has offices in several Zip Codes in all 50 states.  Each year, some new offices are opened, some current offices are closed.  Almost forgot: we have our own designations for the offices.

```
Year   Office Code   Zip Code        Status
2009   Z10           20701           Open
2009   Z11           20703           Open
2009   Z12           20701           Open

2010   Z10           20702           Open
2010   Z11           moved to 20702  Open
2010   Z12           NA              Closed
2010   Z14           20707           Open - Added (didn't exist last year)
```

I have a list of the zip codes in 2009 of our existing offices.  This list of zip codes is different in 2010.

Is there a straightforward way to compare the zip code lists and report on which respective offices have been closed/opened/moved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you want to find those in col. B with no match in col. A. Put in C2:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$26;B2)
```

This will give you 1 (or more) if there's a match, 0 otherwise.

You can also sort both columns individually, then select both, Goto Special, select Row Differences. But that will stop working  after the first new item, and you will have to insert a cell dans start again.

Comment: Upvoted, but things will get a bit weird if you have multiple offices in one zip code.  You really need to compare the office code list from both years to be fully accurate I would suspect.

Comment: @Jody: sure, you have to do it both ways to find out all the diffrences.

Comment: Would it be pretty easy in VBA?

Comment: @Remou: Thanks for the edit; looks good.  How did you fix my post?

Comment: @Doug: I think it's quicker without VBA in this case.

Comment: @iDevlop: Thanks for the answer.  What do I do to acknowledge your help?

Comment: @Doug You can use the code button {} on the toolbar. VBA would be very easy, and you can use ADO with Excel, which gives you all the power of queries.

Comment: @Remou: with joins, etc ??? have you got a "favorite link" for ADO queries on XL ?

Comment: @iDevelop ADO and VBA, you understand, yes with joins and so forth. [How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) [Compare / Match rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166)[Various notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643860/please-suggest-ways-to-manipulate-excel-spreadsheet-without-using-excel-object-as)

Comment: [With MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933544/import-excel-data-to-relational-tables-at-mysql/4934841#4934841) or 
[With SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564532/mvc-load-data-from-excel-to-sqlserver/4564779#4564779)

Comment: Still a mess s/b: [How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335) also [Compare / Match rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166) and [Various notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643860/please-suggest-ways-to-manipulate-excel-spreadsheet-without-using-excel-object-as)